# Why am I returned an object when using std() in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

The print for average of the spreads come out grouped and calculated right. Why do I get this returned as the result for the std_deviation column instead of the standard deviation of the spread grouped by ticker?:
pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x000000000484A588

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\William\\Desktop\\tickdata.csv',
                 dtype={'ticker': str, 'bidPrice': np.float64, 'askPrice':      np.float64, 'afterHours': str},
                 usecols=['ticker', 'bidPrice', 'askPrice', 'afterHours'],
                 nrows=3000000
                 )

df = df[df.afterHours == "False"]
df = df[df.bidPrice != 0]
df = df[df.askPrice != 0]
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)
df['std_deviation'] = df['spread'].std(ddof=0)
df = df.groupby(['ticker'])

print(df['std_deviation'])
print(df['spread'].mean())
```

UPDATE: no longer being returned an object but now trying to figure out how to have the standard deviation displayed by ticker

```
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)
df2 = df.groupby(['ticker'])
print(df2['spread'].mean())

df = df.set_index('ticker')
print(df['spread'].std(ddof=0))
```

UPDATE2: got the dataset I needed using

```
df = df[df.afterHours == "False"]
df = df[df.bidPrice != 0]
df = df[df.askPrice != 0]
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)

print(df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].mean())
print(df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].std(ddof=0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
df = df.groupby(['ticker'])
```

assigns `df` to a DataFrameGroupBy object, and

```
df['std_deviation']
```

is a SeriesGroupBy object (of the column).

*It's a good idea not to "shadow" / re-assign one variable to a completely different datatype. Try to use a different variable name for the groupby!*

Comment: Hey! Thanks to your advice, I'm now being returned something that is not an object. However, now it is returning me one number: the standard deviation of every spread. How can I have the standard deviation grouped by ticker symbol without using groupby? (revised code in OP)

Comment: With groupby you can do `df.groupby(["ticker"])["spread"].std(ddof=0)`.